# How to remediate a CVE or find a work around before the patch is released?

Tags: java, cve

I was going through set of security vulnerabilities reported in [Oracle Critical Patch Update](https://www.oracle.com/security-alerts/cpujan2020.html#AppendixJAVA). I want to find out the standard process followed by developers/security people to mitigate these kind of vulnerabilities before the patch is released. So to ask direct questions..

What is the standard set of steps I should follow to mitigate a security vulnerability before patch is released?

Even after the patch is released, how to find out the severity of the impact of any CVE on my system to determine if application of the patch is really worth the efforts?

I know there is a severity index mentioned on the Oracle and CVE portals for each CVE. However, how do I really check how badly my overall system, which includes multiple servers and multiple web services, is impacted?

Finally, do guide me if I am going in the wrong direction here and point out the right way to deal with CVEs. Thanks!

Comment: What you are really asking is how to perform a **risk assessment** and/or a **threat assessment** on disclosed CVEs to create a mitigation plan.

Comment: @schroeder Yes can you please guide me if you have any pointers, that will be of great help. Any links to docs mentioning some basic steps to follow etc. would also do. Thanks